# Free Syslog Viewers

Tags: gratis, open-source, log-analysis

I have this requirement to ***collect , store , and view / analyze - syslog message***s from few switches in my small office (around 40 - all managed switches).

I searched in google and found few "free" tools , like *syslog-ng , nxlog , ELK stack , and Graylog, Visual Syslog server for Window*s, etc. Most of the tools are Linux based.

I have used sylog-ng to collect and then forward logs to Graylog for log-viewing. But configuring sylog-ng needs a lot of time.

Instead I found another free tool ***Fastvue Syslog*** that I can use for collecting and storing syslog messages of the switches , since "*fastvue syslog*" is for *windows* and has a **GUI** for easy configuration and also has option to *store logs and archive it* .
Fastvue syslog can also forward logs to another destination.
But *Fastvue sysog does not have any GUI for log viewing or log analysis*.

I have tried Graylog for viewing logs , its good but if one of its components (either MongoDB or ElasticSearch) crashes then entire Graylog fails , and I have faced this issue multiple times during machine startup.

Troubleshooting the errors in Graylog and syslog-ng requires a lot of time and effort ,does not work usually and requires a full reinstall.

Please suggest any tool (*prefferably windows*) that I can use to view logs either stored locally or logs collected and forwarded by fastvue.